# Function to return all combinations of n booleans?

Tags: clojure

I am trying to implement a function that takes a number n and returns a list of lists of booleans that contains all possible combinations of n booleans. The output of e.g. `(make-bools 3)` should look like

```
[[false false false]
 [false false true ]
 [false true  false]
 [false true  true ]
 [true  false false]
 [true  false true ]
 [true  true  false]
 [true  true  true ]]
```

I thought of converting the numbers from 0 to (2^n) - 1 to a binary format and use `bit-test` to make a list of booleans, finally chaining all those lists. But that seems quite clumsy to me and I suppose there must be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Try a recursive approach: suppose you know how to do a (make-bools 2), how would you create (make-bools 3): Just by prepending false and true to every element. Generalize this to (make-bools n) expressed as (make-bools n-1) and handle the (make-bools 0) which should result in an empty list.

Comment: Thanks, I thought of a recursion too, but in the wrong way. I'll try this approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it's considered 'cheating' to use an existing library, rather than respond to the algorithmic details of your question, but Clojure-contrib has a set of common combinatorial functions that are useful for calculating permutations:

```
(require '[clojure.contrib.combinatorics :as comb])

(defn make-bools [n]
  (apply comb/cartesian-product (repeat n [true false])))
```

http://richhickey.github.com/clojure-contrib/combinatorics-api.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! Cheating is absolutely permitted - good answer, thanks.

Comment: Cheers. There's one caveat: Be aware that this solution only works for [true false] and not [false true] in the function call to `cartesian-product`... I've just looked at the source for `cartesian-product` and because of the way it tests for an element in each iteration, it will fail if a falsey value is first in the sequence. Still, it works for combinations of everything else, so I won't knock it!

Comment: For future visitors: it's `clojure.math.combinatorics` now.

Answer (score 2):

for also works fine

```
(let [bools [false true]] 
   (for [x bools y bools z bools] [x y z]))
```

Comment: This only works if you know at compile-time how many bools you need. You can't really turn this solution into a function of n.

Answer (score 2):

If you're still looking for a recursive, from-scratch solution (if only to study), here's one that implements a pattern that's often useful for recursively building "paths" through tree structures:

```
(let [bools [true false]]
  (fn combs [n]
    (if (zero? n)
      [[]]
      (for [smaller (combs (dec n))
            b bools]
        (cons b smaller)))))
```

In this case, the "tree" is imaginary (a series of true/false choices), but the same techniques apply.

Comment: This is a really sweet pattern, and well worth remembering. I've got a feeling I'm going to be coming back to this again and again.

Comment: Yes, nice indeed (though it took me a while to get it). Thanks. One can really learn a lot here.