# generating all combinations of binary values

Tags: scheme

basically, given n, eg 3, how can i create a list of values of all combination of T and F

eg. for n = 3, (make-bools 3) should return ((T T T), (T T F), ... (F F F))

This is similar to question [Function to return all combinations of n booleans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777342) but to implement in scheme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most efficient:

```
(define (make-bools n)
  (if (= n 0)
    '()
    (append (addhead 'T (make-bools (- n 1)))
            (addhead 'F (make-bools (- n 1))))))

; Yield copy of l with h added on to head of each list in l
(define (addhead h l)
  (if (null? l)
      l
      (cons (cons h (car l)) (addhead h (cdr l)))))
```

Comment: Works though there is a slight error. You need to return '(()) if n = 0, or else addhead doesnt work on '()

Comment: Good point, and is even a reasonable value for (make-bools 0).

Answer (score 3):

This works in Racket:

```
#lang racket

(define (generate-binary-combinations n)
  (if (zero? n)
      '(())
      (for*/list ((y (in-list (generate-binary-combinations (sub1 n))))
                  (x (in-list '(T F))))
        (cons x y))))

(generate-binary-combinations 3)
> '((T T T) (F T T) (T F T) (F F T) (T T F) (F T F) (T F F) (F F F))

(generate-binary-combinations 0)
> '(())
```